# How to prevent: Don't resize anything in the container div by changing screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

Maybe you can help me. Specifically, I want that the text is always in the same container position depending on the screen resolution. Are there any solutions for this? Do I need a JS function for this? I don't know what to search in order to fix this…

[image: Don´t change text position in Picture]

```
<style>

.logoBar {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

br {
        line-height: 10%;
     }


.container{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 90%;
    height:90%;  
    min-width: 960px;
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 50%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#text {  
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29.5%;
    left: 11%;
    font-size: 115%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.divider{
    width: 2%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}


  </style>

<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Call a variable to know the width of the window
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        $('container').css('width', screenWidth + 'px');
     });

    </script>

<div class="logoBar">
    <img src="picture1.png" style="height: 15%; width: 15%">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <img src="Log-05.png" style="height: 15%; width: 15%">
</div>

<br></br>


<div class="container">
    <center><img src="Picture.png"></center>
<p id="text">20.5</p>

</div>



</body>
```

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.
Probably the solution is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using %s to position the text box(es).

We do absolutely everything that we can in terms of % of width and height of the image. That way responsiveness is automatic.

There is no need to use Javascript. Measure the width and height of the image, the distance down and to the left of the 3 text boxes and the width and height of a text box and put the measurements into CSS variables. CSS can then calculate the correct % top, bottom, width and height as needed. It doesn't matter what units you use to do this measurement, as long as the same unit is used for all of them.

This snippet has measurements to give the idea. You may want to re-measure everything to get better accuracy.

The one outstanding thing that requires thought is the font size. This needs to be responsive rather than be defined in px etc. It is set to 1vw.

The minimum width requirement of the img has been removed so that the image can be seen in its entirety on smaller devices (the user can always zoom if they want). If the minimum is reinstated then there will have to be further thought on the font size to stop it decreasing not in relation to the img size.

```html
<head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logoBar {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

br {
        line-height: 10%;
     }


.container{
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;  
    /*min-width: 960px;*/
    display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    --w: 1354;
    --h: 665;
    --x: 106;
    --boxw: 113;
    --boxh: 20;
    --yvib: 230;
    --ytemp: 294;
    --yspeed: 354;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#vib {
    --y: var(--yvib);
}
#temp {
    --y: var(--ytemp);
}
#speed {
    --y: var(--yspeed);
}
.text {  
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 1vw;
    
    width: calc((var(--boxw) / var(--w)) * 100%);
    height: calc((var(--boxh) / var(--h)) * 100%);    
    
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: calc((var(--y) / var(--h)) * 100%);
    left: calc((var(--x) / var(--w)) * 100%);
    color: red;
}
.divider{
    width: 2%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The top bit commented out as the question is about the main image not this bit
<div class="logoBar">
    <img src="picture1.png" style="height: 15%; width: 15%">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <img src="Log-05.png" style="height: 15%; width: 15%">
</div>

<br></br>

-->
<div class="container" onclick="console.log(event);">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9R3S.png">
   <div id="vib" class="text">20.5</div>
   <div id="temp" class="text">100</div>
   <div id="speed" class="text">50</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. I think that will be the solution.